# Is this strenghthening of Wigner's theorem on quantum symmetries true?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, symmetry, unitarity, foundations

For every nonzero vector $\phi$ in a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, let us denote $[\phi] := \mathbb{C}\phi$ the **ray** associated to $\phi$.

Let $S$ be the set of rays. For all non-zero $\phi,\psi$, $<[\phi],[\psi]> := \vert \langle \phi,\psi\rangle\vert$ is well-defined.

[Wigner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_theorem) states that every bijection $f$ of $S$ preserving $<\cdot, \cdot>$ comes from a unitary or antiunitary operator. Is it still true if we replace the hypothesis "preserve $<\cdot ,\cdot>$" by "for all rays $r_1$, $r_2$, if $<r_1,r_2> = 0$, then $<f(r_1),f(r_2)> = 0$"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is true: U. Uhlhorn, Representation of symmetry transformations in quantum mechanics, Ark. Fys. 23 (1963), 307–340.

Comment: Any proof of Uhlhorn's result in a book? "Ark. Phys." has no internet archive where one can find the article as PDF. Thank you!

Comment: Here you can find a generalisation of the result and this paper is included in the Euclid Project: Orthogonality preserving transformations on the set of 
n
-dimensional subspaces of a Hilbert space
Peter Šemrl
Illinois J. Math. 48(2): 567-573 (Summer 2004). DOI: 10.1215/ijm/1258138399

Comment: Thank you very much! I wonder why Wigner didn’t think of using the fundamental theorem of projective geometry (I suppose he didn’t since the result follows easily from it).